# Copy of Text File

Tags: c, file, text, scanf, printf

this is a code i got from my prof but i dont fully understand it as it reaches the while loop.
Can somebody explain to me the following:

1. `while(fscanf(pin, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF)`
2. `fscanf(pin, "%1[\n]", dummy);`
3. `line[0] = '\0';`

By the way, the text file to be copied contains:

**Line 1**

(Space)

**Line 2**

(Space)

(Space)

**Line 3**

(Space)

(Space)

(Space)

**Line 4**

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define LNAME 31
#define LLINE 81

int main(void)
{
  FILE *pin, *pout; 
  char name_in[LNAME], name_out[LNAME], line[LLINE];
  char dummy[LLINE];

  do
  {
    printf("Enter name of input file : ");
    scanf("%30s", name_in);
    pin = fopen(name_in, "r");
  } while(pin == NULL);

  do
  {
    printf("Enter name of output file: ");
    scanf("%30s", name_out);
    pout = fopen(name_out, "w");
  } while(pout == NULL);


  while(fscanf(pin, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF)
  {

    fprintf(pout, "%s\n", line);    /*In output file */
    printf("%s\n", line);           /*Echo on screen */

    fscanf(pin, "%1[\n]", dummy);   /*skip over '\n' */
    line[0] = '\0';                 /*important, when next line empty!!! */
  }

  fclose(pin);
  fclose(pout);

  printf("\n\n");
  return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should take a look at [fscanf() reference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/io/fscanf). Here's the explanation:

1. `while(fscanf(pin, "%[^\n]", line) != EOF)`:
   Keeps reading any number of characters until it reaches \n into line. When EOF is reached, the code goes on, i.e. while loop is over.
2. `fscanf(pin, "%1[\n]", dummy);`:
   Reads the '\n' and puts it into dummy. This line could be changed to `fscanf(pin, "%*1[\n]");`
3. `line[0] = '\0';`
   This puts the terminating character in the beginning of line, so it can be used to read the next lines.